# Convert date to a number

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro which reads the cell content and opens corresponding files as per the cell value.

For example, if I provide 20140522 in a cell, it opens the file "C:\Files\20140522.csv".

However, instead of providing in the above format if I provide it as 22/05/2014 or more generally today's date, how can I convert it into above format in the vba script itself ?. This is because all my files are in the format shown in example only. Following is my macro code

```
Sub Open()
    num=Cells(1,1).Value
    ActiveWorkbook.Open(FileName:="C:\Files\" & num & ".csv")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Format:

```
num = Format(Cells(1,1).Value, "yyyymmdd")
```

Comment: I have one more task as well. Actually it's not exactly today's date. 20140603 is mapped to 20140522. By that I mean, if I give 20140603 it should open file corresponding to 20140522 as that is the latest one. How can I figure out a way to map the read date i yyyymmdd format to suitable value

Comment: It also would not hurt to properly declare the variable `Dim num as String)`.

Comment: What's the basis for the calculation of the correct date?

Comment: @Rory: As far as I know it's 3 weekdays behind. I want to do it for a general no.of weekdays lag. On weekends there won't be any files. Can this be done ??

Comment: For XL2007 or later: `num = Format(application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(cells(1, 1).value, -3), "yyyymmdd")` and adjust the -3 as required

Comment: There are more than 3 working days between 22 May and 3 June.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim d As Date, sDate As String
    d = Date
    sDate = CStr(Year(d) & Format(Month(d), "00") & Format(Day(d), "00"))
    ActiveWorkbook.Open Filename:="C:\Files\" & sDate & ".csv"
End Sub
```